# Content Security Policy, X-Frame-Options, and localhost

Tags: iframe, content-security-policy, x-frame-options

Kind of a 101 question about `X-Frame-Options` and/or `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors`: if one intends to develop an application using iframed production sites (on which I can adjust headers) on a local machine, would they have to add `localhost` to `frame-ancestors` in the `Content-Security-Policy`? Will `X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN` not work at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to strip those headers from the framed response so they don't prevent rendering.

Locally, the only thing that applies would be frame-src coming in the localhost response allowing you to embed your production sites (not setting csp at all would also work).

Comment: What method would you use to strip the headers? If this is just an `<iframe />` on a page, I don't really get a chance to do the header stripping?

Comment: You would need to use a proxy (e.g. Charles proxy) that removes the headers or a browser extension. There seem to be a few chrome extensions that specifically remove x-frame-options but I haven't tried any so I can't recommend any.